# How to save a 32bpp BMP file store in memory to a 24bpp BMP file?

Tags: windows, bmp

I do have a 32bpp BMP image stored in memory and I want to save it to a 24bpp BMP file.

How can I do that in C/C++ or Python?

Usage of Windows API is acceptable, but not other third party libraries.